# loading specific categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loading

I have developed one wordpress site. In this site I am facing one problem regarding with the loading the categories. There are two particular categories which takes near about two minutes to load. I am not getting the exact solution for this problem.

You can refer url www.deohill.com on this link the categories "Social networking" and "How to" takes time to load.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, your whole site is taking too long to get load..
May be you should ask your hosting provider because i feel your server response is too slow..
Thanks,
Nasir